# Getting error during dex with a project using javafx and apache POI

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, apache-poi, gradle-eclipse

I'm trying to use Apache POI on Android in order to do that i created a gradle project on eclipse but when i execute the gradle task androidInstall i get an error during the dex step. (run task is working)

Here the error:

```
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/EventFilter;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/FactoryConfigurationError;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinder;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/Location;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/StreamFilter;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
... 4 more
16:41:25.082 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:java] Java Result: 2
16:41:25.083 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Setting project property: dexResult -> 2
16:41:25.084 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Dex result value = 2
16:41:25.093 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':dex'
16:41:25.094 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :dex FAILED
16:41:25.095 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :dex (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 2 mins 19.455 secs.
16:41:25.095 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 21 mins 29.722 secs, idle: 0.053 secs
16:41:25.103 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:41:25.108 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:41:25.109 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:41:25.109 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:41:25.109 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':dex'.
16:41:25.110 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
16:41:25.110 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn't come with an
16:41:25.111 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
16:41:25.111 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
16:41:25.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
16:41:25.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
16:41:25.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
16:41:25.115 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
16:41:25.115 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
16:41:25.116 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn't come with an
16:41:25.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
16:41:25.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
16:41:25.140 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
16:41:25.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
16:41:25.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
16:41:25.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
16:41:25.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
16:41:25.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn't come with an
16:41:25.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
16:41:25.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
16:41:25.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
16:41:25.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
16:41:25.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
16:41:25.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
...
```

I read that i needed to add this to ignore warning but i get another error on compileSdkVersion

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

and here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = "JavaFXStage"
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = ['ensemble.**.*']
    }

    android {

        javafxportsVersion = '8u40-b5'
        compileSdkVersion  = 23     
        applicationPackage = 'any.package.name' 

    }
}

dependencies{
    def poiVersion = "3.10.1"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${poiVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${poiVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1"
    compile "org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0"
}
```

If you need more information about the project don't hesitate to ask.

If you have any tips to solve my problem thanks.

Thomas

Comment: It appears xmlbeans is obsolete (last updated 2012, declared obsolete 2014). Why are you still using it? Can you compile your project without it?

Comment: I compile it without xmlbeans and i still have the same error.

Comment: The error log you have attached specifically refers to xmlbeans. What is the new error log?

Comment: I carefully checked the log file and it is still the same file http://pastebin.com/VpyVNVzr

Comment: My point is - there are still lots of errors referring to xmlbeans, which means something still refers it. I don't know enough about android and gradle to tell you where to look, but somewhere there must still be a reference to xmlbeans.

Comment: I think that the reference comes from the library apachePOI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Apache POI on Android does not work out of the box due to a number of limitations. Among one of them is the fact that the xmlbeans jar contains some classes multiple times, which confuses the Android compiler. There are also issues about code from pacakge `javax` and the size of the code.

There are currently two projects which try to solve this:

- https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (maintained by me)
- https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx

Both try to solve this by re-packaging the classes into a more compact jar file which can then be added to an Android application. `Android5xlsx` is based on POI 3.12 currently, `poi-on-android` on 3.15-beta1 and can be re-built against recent versions of POI fairly easily.

Comment: I used the second link because on your project you are using  lint option to solve the problem and i cant as i said before and now i manage to install the app to my device but i get a black screen when i try to launch the app. I will dig in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error in the Dex step by excluding xmlbeans in the gradle.build:

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.16'
compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.16') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', module: 'xmlbeans'
}
```

In my java code I didn't use xmlbeans but other parsers. Here's my import list:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
```